# What does "baby" mean as in "baby spinach"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context

> You’ve seen it in salads and as a popular addition to omelettes and smoothies. While many say they don’t like it, **baby spinach** is a nutrient-dense vegetable that provides some serious health benefits.

I wondering what "baby" means here. I believe it is almost similar to "unripe" as in "unripe tomato", but I'm not sure.

Comment: We don't usually produce or promote "baby" versions of things like ***fruit*** (for which terms like ***ripe/unripe*** are meaningful). I've never seen ***baby tomatoes*** for sale, for example. It's primarily relevant to things like root vegetables *(**baby carrots**)* or salad leaves/brassicas *(**baby spinach**)* where the younger version is likely to be more tender.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Tesco Finest Mixed Baby Tomatoes 250g £1.60

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: There's always an exception. But [they're not exactly "popular".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=baby+tomatoes%2Cbaby+corn%2Cbaby+carrots%2Cbaby+spinach&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I have noticed a tendency for retailers to call small varieties 'baby' - bananas, lemons (Waitrose), etc. Possibly these days you can't say 'midget' or 'dwarf'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I guess I'm just "old school". To me, ***baby*** applied to foodstuffs (that ***grow***) still primarily implies ***young*** rather than ***small***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [Baby corn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_corn), which is so immature that the entire ear can be eaten, cob and all, has been a common ingredient in some East Asian cuisines for as long as I can remember.

Comment: [Definition of baby as an adjective](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/baby_2) : *baby vegetables are a very small version of particular vegetables, or are vegetables that are picked when they are very small*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baby spinach is young spinach (Spinacia oleracea) that has been harvested during the early stages of plant growth, generally between 15 and 35 days after planting. The smaller leaves are more tender and have a sweeter flavour than mature spinach. So similar in meaning to 'unripe', in that it is harvested early in the plant's growth, except that baby spinach is ready to eat and not difficult to digest like unripe fruit might be.

[Baby spinach](https://www.webmd.com/diet/health-benefits-baby-spinach#1)